# Java recursion build error: array required, but string found?

Tags: java, recursion, compiler-errors

I really need help fixing this line of my code, I keep getting these two errors:

First Error: array required, but String found 
if(x.length() == 0 && y.length() > 0 && y[0] == "*")

Second Error: no suitable method found for replace(int,int) String newY = y.replace(0,1);
any help would be appreciated

```
//Second string is empty and there is wildCard character
if(y.length() == 0 && wildCard)
{
    return true;
}
if(x.length() == 0 && y.length() > 0 && y[0] == "*")
{
    String newY = y.replace(0,1);
    return match(x, newY, true);
}
```

Comment: `newY` is a `String`, and your method `match` requires an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

y[0] is for arrays; use y.charAt(0) for strings instead. Furthermore, compare it with '*' (the character), and not with "*" another string.

Comment: thank you so much, but how do i I do this in Java String newY = y.remove(0,1); <----- this doesnt seem to work in java any help?
 {
  String newY = y.replace(0,1);
  return match(x, newY, true);
 }

Comment: So I'm assuming you meant replace: String newY = y.replace(0, 1) won't work, because 0 and 1 are int. Try replace('0', '1'), with chars.

Comment: wanted to remove string y between 0-1

Comment: Then you can use substring. If you want to remove between 0 and 1 inclusive, then you want the string after the second position; just do y.substring(2). If you want to remove between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive), then do: y.charAt(0) + y.substring(2).

Answer (score 3):

In

```
if(x.length() == 0 && y.length() > 0 && y[0] == "*")
```

The `"*"` is a String, not a character.

Also, the `y[0]` does not work with Strings in Java, only arrays. That's likely your problem.